# Detecting when a react native app transitions to "multi-tasking" view on android

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a react native application and I'm trying to capture the event where the user presses the 'recents' button, taking them to the overview of their currently backgrounded apps. I understand that I can catch foreground/background state transitions and that I can't catch when the app is killed, but I'm wondering if it's possible to catch it before it's killed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not run code just before the app is killed. The app is killed instantly that way so any code won't last long. I would focus on the `background` state instead. Or when the main root component is unmounted you could try to do something, but I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: I'm correctly detecting `background` and also unmount, but to my knowledge if I press the 'recents' button, the app isn't killed yet, I'm just on the multitasking menu where I can switch to another app. If the user then swipes the app away the application is killed. I'm wondering can I detect if the user has entered the multitasking view (before they potentially kill the app)